# Probability of $k$ consecutive heads/tails

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I flip $n$ fair coins.

1) Let $p$ denote the probability of seeing a run of length $k$ (i.e. either $k$ consecutive heads, or $k$ consecutive tails). Show that $p \leq n2^{1 - k}$.

2) Observe that if the first run of length $k$ occurs at position $i > 1$, then the coins $i$ and $i - 1$ must have different values. Use this to show that the probability of a run of length $k$ is at most $2^{-k}(n + 1)$.

---

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble with both of these parts. For $(1)$, I know that there are $2^{n}$ total outcomes. Suppose we have a run of length $k$. Then there are $(n - k + 1)$ other coin flips, and we can set them in $2^{n - k + 1}$ ways. Also, we can start the $k$ consecutive coin flips in $(n - k + 1)$ different places (start from first coin flip, second coin flip, etc).

So I think there are $(n - k + 1)2^{n - k + 1}$ ways to get $k$ or more consecutive coin flips out of $2^{n}$ total ways. Is this correct? If so, how can I get the bound given?

Comment: part 2 is really just applying the union bound.  I would suggest doing this for a run of heads only, then revisit for the case of heads or tails runs.  It's conceptually easier to consider this for filliping one fair coin n times in a row though the probabilities are the same

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, if there is a run of $k$ starting on some particular toss, then then next $k-1$ tosses must have the same result.  Since a run of $k$ can start at at most $n+1-k$ coins, there probability of a run of $k$ is less than $(n+1-k)2^{k-1}\leq n2^{k-1}$, because of double-counting runs longer than $k$.